# MySQL: using "when" clause on a field with other fields condition

Tags: mysql

I'll perform an insert into ignore on duplicate key. There's a particular case where I wouldn't like to update a datetime field, in this case it's called **data_ultima_telefonata**.

Here is the entire query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO 'db'.'singolachiamatatesting' ('id_x', 'data_ultima_telefonata',  'operatore',  'status_descrizione','id_status',    'id_centro_lead',   'id_shop',    'data_apt',  'nome_pv','azienda') VALUES 
                   ('25647',
                   '2017-09-19 20:41:17',
                   'EU GUY',
                   'NR SMS Courtesy fissato',
                   '140',
                   '26',
                   '115',
                   '2017-09-21 15:00',
                   'SHOP','PRJXX'),
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 'id_status'=VALUES('id_status'), 'status_descrizione'=
VALUES('status_descrizione'),'data_ultima_telefonata'=CASE  WHEN VALUES('id_status' IN ('100','200') 
THEN VALUES('data_ultima_telefonata') 
ELSE 'data_ultima_telefonata' END, 'data_apt'=VALUES('data_apt')
```

(Keep in mind that quotes on integer fields are being provided directly from C#: it isn't an error!)

This particular case, is when the **id_status** field given by values, it's equal to 100 or 200 (int numeric field). Otherwise, I would update the field **data_ultima_telefonata**.

I tried with this **case** clause condition:

```
CASE  WHEN VALUES('id_status' IN (100, 200) THEN VALUES('data_ultima_telefonata') ELSE 'data_ultima_telefonata' END
```

But it gives me generic error.

Comment: A "generic error"? Something like: "Hey man, there's an error!"?

Comment: do you miss a closed bracket after VALUES ('id_status  and before   IN     ?

Comment: Something like: "you have an error in your query execution".
That's all.

Comment: Why not try to copy in the **exact** error in your question?

Comment: Because the problem is that the given error is what I've written.

If you would like to be aggressive, please give up.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to come across as aggressive. Errors are the first clue as to what might be wrong, hence my question and insistence. MySQL often gives very exact, yet cryptic, error message, they are useful.

Comment: Actually, the instance of mysql class in c# returns that errors, exactly as I've written.
By the way, I've copied the query on mysql workbench and, in conclusion, is how as @etsa said: I've missed a closed bracket.

Sorry for my mistake.